# Can't use post method of any controller after adding facebook social in my Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The controller has @RequestMapping("/api")

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users" ,"/api/books/{id}","/api/authors", "/api/books","/api/categories").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    }
```

Get methods work perfect, but Post doesn't work on the same url's.
Here is an example from one GET and one POST method.

```
 @PostMapping("/users")
    User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return this.userRepository.save(user);
    }
    @GetMapping("/users")
    Collection<User> getUsers(){
        return this.userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

So, GET is working, but POST not.
Post method redirect me to facebook login

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following line

.csrf().disable() at the beginning of the configure method